# Opencart checkout not passing through custom field

Tags: php, opencart

I'm trying to add 2 custom fields to the checkout (one for a gift note, one to let users choose the dispatch date). I managed to get the gift note field up and running fine but I'm having trouble with the date field.

I'm using a standard text field (input type="text") with the intention of using jQuery UI for the date picker, but the value of the text field isn't being passed through. If I change from an input to a textarea the data does get passed through. I'm trying to add them both in the 'Payment Method' stage of the checkout on Opencart 1.5.4.

I'm new to Opencart (started looking at it yesterday when I was asked to add these fields) but understand the MVC+L pattern and, as I say, managed to get one field working and passed into the database. I'm not using vQmod.

The data from the input field just isn't getting passed into $this->request->post in controller/payment_method.php

This seems like a bug to me, is it just a quirk of Opencart? I could technically use a textarea if there isn't a solution but that feels a bit of a dirty way around the problem

Comment: Decided to try using a textarea for the meantime until I found a better solution and discovered that I can't use the jQuery UI datepicker on a textarea so I'm back to square one

Comment: can you please share the code cause i need add extra input text field at checkout step but i do not know how.

i made input text field but looks like i needs to make changes at ajax part in order to post the extra input field value. ~thanks

Comment: There's not really code to share, the way I solved it is below as the accepted answer. If you've added the fields to the checkout page and they're showing up, make sure you give them an id attribute then you can use that id in the jQuery ajax call. In my checkout.tpl file it's on line 871

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in my case, here's what I did in case it helps anyone in the future.

I found that all the AJAX for posting data through is in

*view/theme/**THEME-NAME**/template/checkout/checkout.tpl*

I searched for instances of 'post', checked and checked which section they were relevant to. In my case (adding fields inside the payment_method section), the URL the data was being passed to was

**index.php?route=checkout/payment_method/validate**

and just added the id's of the extra fields into the data attribute of the AJAX call.

Hope this is of use to someone else